# How can I cache a small table data on a Db side?

Tags: cache, postgresql

Say I have a table Statuses in which the data doesn't change for a long time and there're a few records only. I need to use it often in joins. How can I cache data from it on the Db side, in particular, in Posgtresql? Is it possible at all? If it were a bigger table with many rows, I'd use materialized view, but here if I used it, it'd contain the same data the original table does. What else?

Answer (score 1):

Most RDBMS allow standard table constructs, that live only in RAM. While they need to be recreated on database server restart, this should be no show-stopper. A noteable exception is PostgreSQL, where unlogged tables are as close as you get.

Having said this, I recommend you reconsider: All relevant RDBMS - this time definitly including PostgreSQL - use an elaborated caching system, that will keep often-accessed data in RAM: Most likely this does already what you want.